# Índice fuera de los límites de la matriz Arreglo Bidimensional c#

Tags: c#

Estoy haciendo un dibujo y en la parte de la función draw() recibo un arreglo bidimensional y el color

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace drawing
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Graphics drawArea;
        int centerX, centerY, scale;
        int[,] caseG;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            drawArea = drawingArea.CreateGraphics();
            centerX = this.drawingArea.Size.Width / 2;
            centerY = this.drawingArea.Size.Height / 2;
            scale = 10;
            caseG = new int[,] {{1, 3}, {4, 4}, {13, 4}, {15, 3}, {15, 1}, {14, 0}, {13, -3}, {11, -5}, {5, -5}, {2, -3}, {1, 0}};
        }
```

Este es el constructor

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private Point centerPoint(int x, int y)
        {
            return new Point(centerX + (scale * x), centerY + (scale * y));
        }
```

centerPoint se supone debe colocar al centro el valor y se suma con lo que recibe

```
        private void draw(int[,] figure, SolidBrush color)
        {
            Point[] points = new Point[figure.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < figure.Length; i++)
            {
                points[i] = this.centerPoint(figure[i, 0], figure[i, 1]);
            }

            // Fill curve on screen.
            drawArea.FillClosedCurve(color, points);
        }
```

La función draw es lo que debe hacer el dibujo y dónde surge el problema

```
        private void clear()
        {
            drawArea.Clear(Color.Teal);
        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.clear();
            this.draw(caseG, new SolidBrush(Color.Red));
        }
    }
}
```

El error que marca es en la parte de:

```cs
points[i] = this.centerPoint(figure[i, 0], figure[i, 1]);
```

Se supone que debe crear el Point con el arreglo pero marca error

¿A qué se puede deber?.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya había intentado poner `figure.Length - 1` como dicen en otros post pero igual me marca error :c

Comment: Debería ser i < figure.Length -1

Comment: @Eric Ya lo había visto en otro post pero igual me marca el mismo error :c

Comment: pone un punto de interrupción y fijate que cantidad de items tiene cada Array, ahi esta el problema. A modo de ejemplo, el indice fuera de rango es que vos queres poner o tomar del indice 8, y solo tenes 4 en el array. si compartis la parte visual la puedo ejecutar en mi visual y ver el problema

Comment: Cuál es el valor de figure.length que le asignas el tamaño al vector. Si ejecutas paso a paso imprimiendo las variables puedes ver la causa del error.

Comment: ¿Cómo imprimo los valores paso a paso en c#? No estoy muy acostumbrado a c# @Eric

Comment: ¿En que momento de la iteración te falla? ¿Al inicio? ¿Al final? Con un punto de interrupción y debuggeando deberías ver el valor de las variables en ese momento y preguntarte el porqué llega a exceder el tamaño del array.

Comment: Click derecho en la variable y "agregar inspección"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que el Length te toma el total de elementos que tenes en el array bidimensional, entonces tenes 11 registros con 2 elementos por linea, y el Length te marca 22, ahi es el error de fuera de indice, no se si es la mejor solucion pero divides el length por la cantidad de dimensiones y te dara el valor total de filas.

```
for (int i = 0; i < figure.Length /2; i++)
{
    points[i] = this.centerPoint(figure[i, 0], figure[i, 1]);
}
```

Edito para una forma distinta de realizarlo aunque no era esa la pregunta.
Segunda opcion es:

```
public class PointNew
{
    public int PointX { get; set; }
    public int PointY { get; set; }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Graphics drawArea;
    int centerX, centerY, scale;
    int[,] caseG;
    List<PointNew> puntos = new List<PointNew>();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        scale = 10;

        puntos.Add(new PointNew { PointX = 1, PointY = 3 });
        puntos.Add(new PointNew { PointX = 4, PointY = 4 });
        puntos.Add(new PointNew { PointX = 13, PointY = 4 });
        puntos.Add(new PointNew { PointX = 15, PointY = 3 });
        puntos.Add(new PointNew { PointX = 15, PointY = 1 });
        puntos.Add(new PointNew { PointX = 14, PointY = 0 });
        puntos.Add(new PointNew { PointX = 13, PointY = -3 });
        puntos.Add(new PointNew { PointX = 11, PointY = -5 });
        puntos.Add(new PointNew { PointX = 5, PointY = -5 });
        puntos.Add(new PointNew { PointX = 2, PointY = -3 });
        puntos.Add(new PointNew { PointX = 1, PointY = 0 });

        this.draw(caseG, new SolidBrush(Color.Red));
    }
    private Point centerPoint(int x, int y)
    {
        return new Point(centerX + (scale * x), centerY + (scale * y));
    }
    private void draw(int[,] figure, SolidBrush color)
    {
        Point[] points = new Point[puntos.Count];
        int A = 0;
        foreach (var item in puntos)
        {
            points[A] = this.centerPoint(item.PointX, item.PointY);
            A++;
        }
        // Fill curve on screen.
        drawArea.FillClosedCurve(color, points);
    }
    private void clear()
    {
        drawArea.Clear(Color.Teal);
    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.clear();
        this.draw(caseG, new SolidBrush(Color.Red));
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Exacto, estaba viendo eso, en c# te da el numero total de dimensiones

Comment: figure.GetLength(0) Se tiene que utilizar esto para especificar la dimensión de la que quiero sacar el length

Comment: Lo podrias resolver tambien, creando un objeto (Clase) con propiedad ( x , y ) y con esa clase haces un list<Point> y recorres con foreach, entonces no tenes que andar dividiendo el Length. Me explico?

Comment: No entiendo a lo que te refieres :c @Ramiro Barone

Comment: Va como segunda respuesta.